# IIS error : ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer and ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I got this error repeatedly, the site is working fine, but found these errors in the logs files,
and these errors repeated continuously. how can i get the issue?

ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer|Connection ID "", Request ID "": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Comment: That means there were unhandled exceptions caught and ignored. If you want to change the behavior and learn more about the exceptions, you can follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: It's impossible to analyze the problem based on these errors alone, please check if there are more detailed error messages, is the first error you get after running the application? The second error is what request did you perform? please post more details information about your requirement.